# Automapper and custom value resolver with interfaces complains with "The type must be convertible to IValueResolver..."

Tags: c#, automapper

I am currently migrating a larger solution to the latest Automapper version (4.2.1 -> 9.0.0). The abstract class `ValueResolver` has been replaced by the generic interface `IValueResolver` which now allows access to the source/destination models, which is great. I was able to migrate a bunch of our custom value revolvers without any issues. So far so good.

However I just don't understand why the compiler complains in this specific case with the error message bellow. As the resolver's signature does match the constraint types given on the mapping profile...

> The type '...FooTypeResolver' must be convertible to
>   'Automapper.IValueResolver' in
>   order to use it as parameter 'TValueResolver' in the generic method
>   'void AutoMapper.IMemberConfiguration.MapFrom()'

This is my profile and custom value resolver. What am I doing wrong here?

```cs
public abstract class ABaseMappingProfile<TSrc, TDst> : Profile 
    where TSrc : IProductRelated 
    where TDst : SomeType
{  
    protected AMappingProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<TSrc, TDst>()
            // ...
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AStringProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom<FooTypeResolver>())
    }
}

public class FooTypeResolver : IValueResolver<IProductRelated, SomeType, string>
{
    public string Resolve(IProductRelated source, SomeType destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

---

As addendum to @LucianBargaoanu comment. The following works. I still don't get why the attempt from above does not.

```
public class AnotherMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public AnotherMappingProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<IProductRelated, SomeType>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AStringProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom<FooTypeResolver>());
    }
}
```

---

Changing the constraint `TSrc` from `IProductRelated` to a concrete class makes it work. This however is no feasible solution in my situation.

**Why am I not able to use an interface in this case?**

Comment: Try it without the generic profile class.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, thanks for replying. Please see my modified question.

Comment: The standard way to reuse configuration is [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html).